# How to pause or slow down/speed up Time.deltaTime when it is inside the Update() method?

Tags: unity, c#, timer, time, deltatime

My player is able to dive for a limited amount of seconds (let's say 10 seconds) while swimming. When he's not diving his breath gauge fills up again to a max of 10 seconds:

```
private bool isFreediving;
private float breath = 10f;

void Update()
{
    if (isFreediving)
    {
        if (breath > 0)
        {
            breath -= Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(breath);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Out of breath");
            breath = 0; // optional?
            isFreediving = false;
            // Do staff...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (breath == 0)
        {
            // TODO: Make the player stop moving for 1 second
            // TODO: Stop breath += Time.deltaTime for 3 seconds
        }
        else if (breath > 0 && breath < 10)
        {
            breath += Time.deltaTime; // TODO: Make breath fill up slower/faster
            Debug.Log(breath);
        }
    }
}
```

If the player runs out of breath completely, I want him to stop moving for a second and I also want the breath gauge to not start to fill up for 3 seconds. I tried with ***coroutines***, but my code is inside the `Update()` method, so it didn't work. I realize that the above `If`-`else` statements need to be rearranged properly.

Lastly, I want the breath gauge to be filled up at a different pace, for example:

```
breath += Time.deltaTime * 0.5f;
```

I wonder if there is a better way?

EDIT: After @Pow's solution:

```
float swimSpeed = 0.03f;
private bool isFreediving;
private float breath = 10f;
private bool canRefillBreath;

void Update()
{
    float swimAmount = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * swimSpeed;
    transform.Translate(0, swimAmount, 0);

    if (isFreediving)
    {
        if (breath > 0) breath -= Time.deltaTime;
        else
        {
            breath = 0;
            isFreediving = false;
            // Do staff...    
            canRefillBreath = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (breath == 0)
        {
            swimSpeed = 0;
            Invoke(nameof(EnableSwim), 1f);
            Invoke(nameof(EnableRefill), 3f);
        }
        if (canRefillBreath && breath < 10) breath += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}    

private void EnableSwim() => swimSpeed = 0.03f;
private void EnableRefill() => canRefillBreath = true;
```

The only weird thing is that after 1 second the player starts moving at a slower rate until the 3 seconds `Invoke(nameof(EnableRefill), 3f);`, then he goes full speed.

Comment: Isn't that because you set swimSpeed to 0.03f after one second? `Invoke(nameof(EnableSwim), 1f);`

Comment: _0.03f_ is the default speed, but the player doesn't move at that speed after 1 second. He's slower for the first two seconds until the 3 seconds of the `EnableRefill` run out. `EnableSwim` and `EnableRefill` shouldn't affect each other, but they do. Perhaps the contemporarity slows the cpu, although the two _Invokes_ don't consume much memory.

Comment: the Invokes wouldn't effect the CPU at all, you've probably just missed something somewhere in your code.

Comment: I agree. All the relevant code is in the _EDIT_ above. Everything seems ok unless I don't properly understand the Unity life cycle.

Comment: I would highly reccomend you dont use Transform.Translate to move, as it completely ignores physics, that could also be the reason why.

Comment: I learned _transform.translate_ from a well-known course. I'm guessing they have their reasons for teaching it. Maybe it's a good starting point. Otherwise, I don't know what to say.

Comment: Its probably a good starting point, but if you just move the object, it doesn't actually use any physics. It will be stuttery, go through things, and likely look unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to make something happen only once/after a delay in the Update function is to use booleans, simple yet effective. You can use the `Invoke()` method to enable/disable booleans when needed.

Heres an example using your script:

```
private bool runOutOfBreath = false;
private bool canRefillBreath = false;
void Update()
{
    if (isFreediving)
    {
        if (breath > 0)
        {
            runOutOfBreath = false;
            breath -= Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(breath);
        }
        else
        {
            runOutOfBreath = true;
            Debug.Log("Out of breath");
            breath = 0; // optional?
            isFreediving = false;
            // Do staff...
        }
    }
    else {
        if (runOutOfBreath) {
            // your function/coroutine.
            runOutOfBreath = false;
            canRefillBreath = false;
        }
        if (canRefillBreath && breath < 10) {
            breath += Time.deltaTime; // TODO: Make breath fill up slower/faster
            Debug.Log(breath);
        }
        if (breath == 0) {
            Invoke(nameof(EnableRefill), 3f);
        }
    }
}
private void EnableRefill() {
    canRefillBreath = true;
}
```

**NOTE:** you may want to move the if (runOutOfBreath) somewhere else depending on your use case. Right now it only checks if you've run out *and* your not diving. Hope this fixes your issue and let me know if you have any problems :)

Comment: The last condition can be simplified since it double checks if breath is below 10 and equals 0

Comment: oh I missed a section, ill edit it in

Comment: Nice solution. Tried Invoke before, but this time works. I don't really need the `runOutOfBreath` part. I'm doing the _prevent player from moving_ part with `transform.Translate(0, 0, 0);`.